# Carregar BLOB para Image C# MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

Estou tentando carregar uma imagem salva em MySQL, no entanto ainda sem sucesso. Com o código abaixo eu consigo exibir todos os outros campos. Toda vez que eu tento adicionar algum método para exibir a imagem, ocorre algum erro que não exibe nenhuma informação da pesquisa.

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=portaria;Uid=root;Pwd=''");
                conn.Open();

                //Inserindo um comando para acessar o funcionário cadastrado
                MySqlCommand consultar = new MySqlCommand(
                    "SELECT funcID, funcRG, funcNome, funcEmpresa, funcSetor, funcRamal, funcFoto, funcStatus " +
                    "FROM funcionario WHERE funcRG = ?", conn);

                consultar.Parameters.Clear();
                consultar.Parameters.Add("@funcRG",MySqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = txtRG.Text;
                consultar.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                //Recebendo o conteúdo da pesquisa
                MySqlDataReader info;
                info = consultar.ExecuteReader();
                info.Read();

                //Passando as informações para os campos
                lblNumID.Text = info.GetString(0);
                txtNome.Text = info.GetString(2);
                txtEmpresa.Text = info.GetString(3);
                txtSetor.Text = info.GetString(4);
                txtFone.Text = info.GetString(5);
                //pictureCadastro.Text = info.GetString(6); ------>>>>> Falta carregar a imagem
                cBoxStatus.Text = info.GetString(7);

                conn.Close();
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Pera, você quer jogar a imagem em um campo de texto?

Comment: Primeiro, você está utilizando o método `GetString()` se a coluna armazena um blob, deveria ser o `GetBytes()`... depois, você está tentando jogar esse conteúdo em um `TextBox`? É apresentada alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Quero jogar a imagem em um pictureBox, eu utilizo o mesmo elemento para salvar a imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema utilizando o código do link do site [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/598516/showplusimageplusfromplusdatabaseplustopluspicture#answer3).

Answer (score 0):

```js
string base64string = info.GetString(6);
byte[] blobImage = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blobImage))
{
 pictureCadastro.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Como ainda estou aprendendo a desenvolver na linguagem, ainda estou com um pouco de dificuldade e ainda não consegui entender como usar o código acima. Eu posso incluir no código que eu colei na postagem para que ele execute direto no botão que eu criei? O "BLOB_String" é a variável que eu converti de image para BLOB?

Comment: Alterei a resposta pra funcionar de acordo com o seu código. Adicione e teste.

Comment: Explicando rapidamente, recupero o valor e armazeno na variável `base64string` e logo em seguida transformo em um array de bytes, entao transformo o array de bytes em imagem usando Stream.

Comment: Fiz o teste, mas infelizmente a imagem não aparece. Antes de colocar o código a informação deste campo (cBoxStatus.Text = info.GetString(7);) aparece, mas após inserir o código, não aparece e também tenho uma mensagem de erro (estou usando o código da pergunta em um try/catch). O que será que estou fazendo de errado?